# How to display German Umlaut characters through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript:

```
 $( "#calculatorFromId" ).autocomplete({
                 source: function( request, response ) {
                     $.ajax({
                         url: "${autosuggestCurrenciesUrl}",
                         dataType: "json",
                         data: {
                             term: request.term
                         },
                         success: function( data ) {
                                response(data);

                         }
                     });
                 },
                minLength: 2,
                delay: 0,
focus: function(event, ui) {

$( "#calculatorFromId").
val(ui.item.label.replace('&auml;','ä').replace('&uuml;','ü').
replace('&ouml;','ö').replace('&Auml;','Ä').replace('&Uuml;','Ü').#
replace('&Ouml;','Ö') + "(" + ui.item.id +")");
return false;
}
```

The German Umlaut is not correctly displayed. 
Do you know what value should I pass for the second argument in the **replace** function ?
Every value I pass, it is displayed in the textfield exactly how it was passed.
No conversion is done.

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't the second argument right? What is the value of `ui.item.label`? Maybe you can `console.log` the original, and after replacing, and post it here.

Comment: Note that `.replace`, when given a string for the search argument, only replaces the **first** match. To do a global replace, you have to use a regular expression with the "global" flag (`g`) as the search argument, e.g.: `.replace(/\&auml;/g, 'ä')`.

Comment: I mean, "ä" is displayed as "Ã¤" in the text field. The match is correctly done. The problem is about the way the Umlaut ä, in order to be correctly displayed

Comment: _“I mean, "ä" is displayed as "Ã¤" in the text field”_ – that means you have a character encoding problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: I have tried to change the charset, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Then you have not done it properly … you really _should_ be using UTF-8, everything else does not make sense for current web applications/web sites.

Answer (score 0):

The response text must be *urlencoded* and your local javascript must decode this encoded text with *unescape()*. So you can bypass german umlaute.

Answer (score 0):

To add text with German special characters via JavaScript you could use String.fromCharCode(220) (=Ü)
To find the code for a character use http://unicode-table.com/
example:
var text = String.fromCharCode(220) + "berschrift" (=Überschrift)